# Converting PowerPoint with complex text to a Unicode text file

Tags: macros, microsoft-powerpoint, textfiles

I [found](https://www.rdpslides.com/pptfaq/FAQ00274_Export_Text_to_a_text_file-_extract_text_from_PowerPoint_-Mac_or_PC-.htm) the following macro code for converting a PowerPoint file to a text file:

```
Sub ExportText()

  Dim oPres As Presentation
  Dim oSlides As Slides
  Dim oSld As Slide         'Slide Object
  Dim oShp As Shape         'Shape Object
  Dim iFile As Integer      'File handle for output
  iFile = FreeFile          'Get a free file number
  Dim PathSep As String
  Dim FileNum As Integer
  Dim sTempString As String

  #If Mac Then
    PathSep = ":"
  #Else
    PathSep = "\"
  #End If

  Set oPres = ActivePresentation
  Set oSlides = oPres.Slides

  FileNum = FreeFile

  'Open output file
  ' NOTE:  errors here if file hasn't been saved
  Open oPres.Path & PathSep & "AllText.TXT" For Output As FileNum

  For Each oSld In oSlides    'Loop thru each slide
    ' Include the slide number (the number that will appear in slide's
    ' page number placeholder; you could also use SlideIndex
    ' for the ordinal number of the slide in the file
    Print #iFile, "Slide:" & vbTab & cstr(oSld.SlideNumber)

    For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes                'Loop thru each shape on slide
      'Check to see if shape has a text frame and text
      If oShp.HasTextFrame And oShp.TextFrame.HasText Then
        If oShp.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
            Select Case oShp.PlaceholderFormat.Type
                Case Is = ppPlaceholderTitle, ppPlaceholderCenterTitle
                    Print #iFile, "Title:" & vbTab & oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
                Case Is = ppPlaceholderBody
                    Print #iFile, "Body:" & vbTab & oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
                Case Is = ppPlaceholderSubtitle
                    Print #iFile, "SubTitle:" & vbTab & oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
                Case Else
                    Print #iFile, "Other Placeholder:" & vbTab & oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
            End Select
        Else
            Print #iFile, vbTab & oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
        End If  ' msoPlaceholder
      Else  ' it doesn't have a textframe - it might be a group that contains text so:
        If oShp.Type = msoGroup Then
            sTempString = TextFromGroupShape(oShp)
            If Len(sTempString) > 0 Then
                Print #iFile, sTempString
            End If
        End If
      End If    ' Has text frame/Has text

    Next oShp
  Next oSld

  'Close output file
  Close #iFile

End Sub

Function TextFromGroupShape(oSh As Shape) As String
' Returns the text from the shapes in a group
' and recursively, text within shapes within groups within groups etc.

    Dim oGpSh As Shape
    Dim sTempText As String

    If oSh.Type = msoGroup Then
        For Each oGpSh In oSh.GroupItems
            With oGpSh
                If .Type = msoGroup Then
                    sTempText = sTempText & TextFromGroupShape(oGpSh)
                Else
                    If .HasTextFrame Then
                        If .TextFrame.HasText Then
                            sTempText = sTempText & "(Gp:) " & .TextFrame.TextRange.Text & vbCrLf
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next
    End If

    TextFromGroupShape = sTempText

NormalExit:
    Exit Function

Errorhandler:
    Resume Next

End Function
```

But it does not work for complex texts, e.g Arabic texts. I need to make a Unicode text file from a PowerPoint file that can contain Complex text. How can I modify the above code to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I could fix the problem:

```
Sub ExportText()

  Dim oPres As Presentation
  Dim oSlides As Slides
  Dim oSld As Slide         'Slide Object
  Dim oShp As Shape         'Shape Object
  Dim iFile As Integer      'File handle for output
  iFile = FreeFile          'Get a free file number
  Dim PathSep As String
  Dim FileNum As Integer
  Dim sTempString As String

  #If Mac Then
    PathSep = ":"
  #Else
    PathSep = "\"
  #End If

  Set oPres = ActivePresentation
  Set oSlides = oPres.Slides

  FileNum = FreeFile

  'Open output file

  Set fsObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set xmlFile = fsObject.CreateTextFile(oPres.Path & PathSep & "AllText.txt", True, True) 'the second "true" forces a unicode file.
 
  

  For Each oSld In oSlides    'Loop thru each slide
    ' Include the slide number (the number that will appear in slide's
    ' page number placeholder; you could also use SlideIndex
    ' for the ordinal number of the slide in the file
    xmlFile.writeline "Slide:" & vbTab & CStr(oSld.SlideNumber)

    For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes                'Loop thru each shape on slide
      'Check to see if shape has a text frame and text
      If oShp.HasTextFrame And oShp.TextFrame.HasText Then
        If oShp.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
            Select Case oShp.PlaceholderFormat.Type
                Case Is = ppPlaceholderTitle, ppPlaceholderCenterTitle
                     xmlFile.writeline "Title:" & vbTab & oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
                Case Is = ppPlaceholderBody
                     xmlFile.writeline "Body:" & vbTab & oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
                Case Is = ppPlaceholderSubtitle
                     xmlFile.writeline "SubTitle:" & vbTab & oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
                Case Else
                     xmlFile.writeline "Other Placeholder:" & vbTab & oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
            End Select
        Else
            xmlFile.writeline vbTab & oShp.TextFrame.TextRange
        End If  ' msoPlaceholder
      Else  ' it doesn't have a textframe - it might be a group that contains text so:
        If oShp.Type = msoGroup Then
            sTempString = TextFromGroupShape(oShp)
            If Len(sTempString) > 0 Then
                 xmlFile.writeline sTempString
            End If
        End If
      End If    ' Has text frame/Has text

    Next oShp
  Next oSld

  'Close output file
  xmlFile.Close

End Sub

Function TextFromGroupShape(oSh As Shape) As String
' Returns the text from the shapes in a group
' and recursively, text within shapes within groups within groups etc.

    Dim oGpSh As Shape
    Dim sTempText As String

    If oSh.Type = msoGroup Then
        For Each oGpSh In oSh.GroupItems
            With oGpSh
                If .Type = msoGroup Then
                    sTempText = sTempText & TextFromGroupShape(oGpSh)
                Else
                    If .HasTextFrame Then
                        If .TextFrame.HasText Then
                            sTempText = sTempText & "(Gp:) " & .TextFrame.TextRange.Text & vbCrLf
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next
    End If

    TextFromGroupShape = sTempText

NormalExit:
    Exit Function

Errorhandler:
    Resume Next

End Function
```

But you may need to open the AllText.txt file with Notepad and save it again with the Unicode format you need.

Comment: Nicely done!  I maintain the site where you found the original code and have added a note about this problem and a link back to this page.  Thanks!

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Thanks.